# How to fix the error in left-recursion used with semantic predicates?

Tags: java, antlr4, left-recursion

I would like to parse two type of expression with boolean :
- the first would be an init expression with boolean like : `init : false`
- and the last one would be a derive expression with boolean like : `derive : !express or (express and (amount >= 100))`

My idea is to put semantic predicates in a set of rules,
the goal is when I'm parsing a boolean expression beginning with the word 'init' then it has to go to only one alternative rule proposed who is **boolliteral**, the last alternative in **boolExpression**. And if it's an expression beginning with the word 'derive' then it could have access to all alternatives of **boolExpression**.

I know that I could make two type of boolExpression without semantic predicates like boolExpressionInit and boolExpressionDerive... But I would like to try with my idea if it's could work with a only one boolExpression with semantic predicates.

Here's my grammar

```
grammar TestExpression;

@header
{
package testexpressionparser;
}

@parser::members {
                    int vConstraintType;
                 }

/* SYNTAX RULES */
textInput       : initDefinition 
                | derDefinition ;

initDefinition  : t=INIT {vConstraintType = $t.type;} ':' boolExpression ;

derDefinition   : t=DERIVE {vConstraintType = $t.type;} ':' boolExpression ;

boolExpression  : {vConstraintType != INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? boolExpression (boolOp|relOp) boolExpression 
                | {vConstraintType != INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? NOT boolExpression
                | {vConstraintType != INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? '(' boolExpression ')' 
                | {vConstraintType != INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? attributeName
                | {vConstraintType != INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? numliteral
                | {vConstraintType == INIT || vConstraintType == DERIVE}? boolliteral
                ;

boolOp          : OR | AND ;
relOp           : EQ | NEQ | GT | LT | GEQT | LEQT ;
attributeName   : WORD;
numliteral      : intliteral | decliteral;
intliteral      : INT ;
decliteral      : DEC ;
boolliteral     : BOOLEAN;


/* LEXICAL RULES */
INIT            : 'init';
DERIVE          : 'derive';
BOOLEAN         : 'true' | 'false' ;
BRACKETSTART    : '(' ;
BRACKETSTOP     : ')' ;
BRACESTART      : '{' ;
BRACESTOP       : '}' ;
EQ              : '=' ;
NEQ             : '!=' ;
NOT             : '!' ;
GT              : '>' ;
LT              : '<' ;
GEQT            : '>=' ;
LEQT            : '<=' ;
OR              : 'or' ;
AND             : 'and' ;
DEC             : [0-9]* '.' [0-9]* ;
INT             : ZERO | POSITIF;
ZERO            : '0';
POSITIF         : [1-9] [0-9]* ;
WORD            : [a-zA-Z] [_0-9a-zA-Z]* ;
WS              : (SPACE | NEWLINE)+ -> skip ;
SPACE           : [ \t] ;                       /* Space or tab */
NEWLINE         : '\r'? '\n' ;                  /* Carriage return and new line */
```

I except that the grammar would run successfully, but what i receive is : "error(119): TestExpression.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [boolExpression]
1 error(s)
BUILD FAIL"

Comment: The error message seems a tad misleading (claiming there's mutual left-recursion when the left recursion is actually direct), but it looks like ANTLR4's support for left recursion does not work with predicated. Can you explain what the predicate is for and when `vConstraintType` changes its value? Please also post an [MCVE].

Comment: @sepp2k, I re edited my post with a better explanation about what i would like try to do and with a minimal reproducible example as you requested.

Comment: Have you tried to move semantic predicates from the begin to something else? Also, I think it can be rewritten without semantic predicates at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently ANTLR4's support for (direct) left-recursion does not work when a predicate appears before a left-recursive rule invocation. So you can fix the error by moving the predicate after the first `boolExpression` in the left-recursive alternatives.

That said, it seems like the predicates aren't really necessary in the first place - at least not in the example you've shown us (or the one before your edit as far as I could tell). Since a `boolExpression` with the constraint type `INIT` can apparently only match `boolLiteral`, you can just change `initDefinition` as follows:

```
initDefinition  : t=INIT ':' boolLiteral ;
```

Then `boolExpression` will always have the constraint type `DERIVE` and no predicates are necessary anymore.

Generally, if you want to allow different alternatives in non-terminal `x` based on whether it was invoked by `y` or `z`, you should simply have multiple versions of `x` and then call one from `y` and the other from `z`. That's usually a lot less hassle than littering the code with actions and predicates.

Similarly it can also make sense to have a rule that matches more than it should and then detect illegal expressions in a later phase instead of trying to reject them at the syntax level. Specifically beginners often try to write grammars that only allow well-typed expressions (rejecting something like `1+true` with a syntax error) and that never works out well.

Comment: It's true that, I could have done simply like your example without the predicates. But I had limited the constraint type init on my example also simplified the rule boolExpression. Actually, i'm trying to parse 4 type of constraints with different kind of boolean expression. This is why i was trying to use semantic predicates in only one rule boolExpression who describe multiple alternative of boolean expression than writting multiple version of boolExpression for each constraint in diferrent rules.

Comment: But you're right that it's hassle to write the code with actions and predicates... I'll see if my code is lisible or not. Anyways, you helped me a lot and it's working now. Thanks a lot.